# Global Name Create is not Defined in django

Tags: django, django-forms

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
  name="Rishabh"
  numbers=[1,2,3,4,5]
  args={'name':name, 'numbers':numbers}
  return render(request, "accounts/home.html",args)

def register(request):
  if request.method=='POST':
    form=UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/account')
else:
    form=UserCreationForm()
    args={'form':form}
    return render(request,'accounts/reg_form.html',args)
```

while running this code I get an error called global name create is not defined. I cannot even create a user by admin too

Comment: so first you don't put the `form=...` in the `else` statement. second did you ever check if your form was valid at some point? you can do that by putting a `print("TEST_valid")` under `if form.is_valid():` and check the console if the form is checked when you load the form. What is your exact Error? The error you are giving here does not make sense since "create" is nowhere mentioned in your code. Please add your models.py! If you cannot create a User in the admin or Terminal you are having other problems as well which you take care of first.

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace??

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in your view,

```
def register(request): 
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save() 
            return redirect('/account') 
    else: 
        form=UserCreationForm()
    args={'form':form}
    return render(request,'accounts/reg_form.html',args)
```